# How to set camel case using IAsyncCollector with System.Text.Json in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, serialization, azure-functions, azureservicebus, system.text.json

I'm migrating Azure Functions v3 from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` and trying to get camelCase working globally.

For these:

- SignalR
- Service Bus output bindings
- Cosmos DB

I was able to explicitly pass `JsonSerializerOptions` or set it globally (SignalR) but I'm not able to do so for `IAsyncCollector`.

Here is my code:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(SampleFunction))]
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger(ServiceBusQueue.QueueA)] string json,
    [ServiceBus(ServiceBusQueue.QueueB)] IAsyncCollector<Delivery> queueB,
    [ServiceBus(ServiceBusQueue.QueueC)] IAsyncCollector<Driver> queueC,
    ExecutionContext context)
{
        // ... do some work

        await queueB.AddAsync(objectB).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // ... do some more work

        await queueC.AddAsync(objectC).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

`objectB` and `objectC` ends up in service bus not with camel case. As a workaround I'm setting property names as case insensitive on the receiving function.

```
PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
```

Any idea how can I get `IAsyncCollector` to serialize with camel case?

Comment: How were you setting camel case globally for `IAsyncCollector` when using Json.NET?

Comment: @dbc I was not. My models had `JsonProperty` attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend not using `IAsyncCollector` at all. The providers for `IAsyncCollector` don't have many knobs for configuration:

- Serialization
- Batching
- Retries
- Error handling

What's more, some implementations have *changed* these implementation details between releases without warning. For these reasons, I recommend never using `IAsyncCollector` and just using the APIs directly, where you have full control over all of these aspects. `IAsyncCollector` is a nice abstraction, but it's precisely that abstract nature that makes it unsuitable in the end.

Comment: I like the simplicity of it but you have a very good point there. Without ability to configure those aspects it's pretty much useless.